# Advanced compare in GIT

Tags: git, compare, git-diff

Hello I would like to compare in git two projects. My MAIN project with my employee project but without one folder. Anybody knows how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` for that. Like this:

```
diff -Naur project1/ project2/
```

`-N` `--new-file` - Treat absent files as empty.

`-a` `--text` - Treat all files as text.

`-u` `-U NUM` `--unified[=NUM]` - Output NUM (default 3) lines of unified context.

`-r` `--recursive` - Recursively compare any subdirectories found.